# Displays the image on the flipview, when the image on the gridview is clicked

Tags: c#, json, gridview, uwp, flipview

I have json as below:[image: JSON]

I want to display the data in the gallery on the gridview, then if the user clicks the image on the gridview, it will show a picture with a larger size on the flipview according to the selected image. I'm having trouble, that is when the image on the gridview is selected, it always shows up the image on the flipview for the first index (not in accordance with the picture chosen by the user).

XAML:

```
<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="ArticleDetail" 
                       Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Title="" 
                       Background="White" BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="White" >
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,5,5" Background="{x:Null}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                <StackPanel Height="auto">
                    <ProgressRing x:Name="articleDetailLoading" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Width="50" />
                    <StackPanel x:Name="articleDetailBox" Margin="0,0,10,10" Height="auto">
                        <Grid x:Name="articleDetailGrid" BorderBrush="#FF990000" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="articleIdDetail" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <AppBarButton x:Name="closeArticleBtn" Icon="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" Click="closeArticleBtn_Click"/>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="articleTitleScroll" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="650" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="articleTitleDetail" Margin="0,0,15,15" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" FontWeight="SemiBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="auto" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="articleDateDetail" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10,15,10,0" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Segoe UI Black" FontWeight="SemiLight" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="auto" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                            <GridView x:Name="articleImageGridView" Grid.Row="5" Margin="10,25,10,0" Height="110" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemDetailScrollViewer" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=itemListView}"
                                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                                  ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemClick="articleImageGridView_ItemClick">
                                <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid Height="90" Width="120" Margin="5,0,0,0" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FF646464" BorderThickness="0.5">
                                            <Border x:Name="coverBox" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="120" Height="90" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.5">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="images/IP-placeholder.png"/>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                                <Image x:Name="cover" Source="{Binding ImageURL1}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Uniform" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened" Loaded="cover_Loaded" Loading="cover_Loading"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemTemplate>

                                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" />
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            </GridView>
                            <WebView x:Name="articleContentDetail" Grid.Row="6" Margin="10,15,10,10" Width="650" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>

                    <StackPanel x:Name="articleFullImageDetailBox" Margin="0,0,10,10" Height="auto" Visibility="Collapsed">
                        <Grid x:Name="articleFullImageDetailGrid" BorderBrush="#FF990000" BorderThickness="1">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <AppBarButton x:Name="closearticleFullImageBtn" Grid.Column="1" Icon="Clear" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="Black" Click="closearticleFullImageBtn_Click"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="articleFullIdDetail" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding ID}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            <FlipView x:Name="articleImageFullFlipview" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding gallery.Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding gallery, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="650" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}">
                                <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid x:Name="content" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                                            <Border x:Name="coverBox" Width="600" Height="500">
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="images/IP-placeholder.png"/>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                                <Image x:Name="cover" Source="{Binding ImageURLFull}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding ID}" ImageOpened="Image_ImageOpened" Loaded="cover_Loaded" Loading="cover_Loading"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                            </FlipView>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </callisto:CustomDialog>
```

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<ArticleClass> articleDatasourceDetailImage = new ObservableCollection<ArticleClass>();
            articleDatasourceDetailImage.Clear();
            articleDetailLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            articleDetailLoading.IsActive = true;
            articleDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            articleFullImageDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ArticleDetail.IsOpen = true;
            articleItemDetail = e.ClickedItem as ArticleClass;
            articleIdDetail.Text = articleItemDetail.ID.ToString();

            ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
            if (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
            {
                articleDetailLoading.IsActive = true;
                try
                {
                    string urlPath = "http://indonesia-product.com/api/v1/articles/"10.json?module=articles&page=1&token=3f63-dc43-c8d5-eb45-8cbf-b72d-9d98-800f";
                    //Debug.WriteLine(urlPath.ToString());
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler());

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {

                    };

                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlPath);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
                        RequestException();
                    }

                    string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                    JsonObject jsonData = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                    JsonObject groupObject1 = jsonData.GetObject();

                    double id = groupObject1["id"].GetNumber();
                    string title = groupObject1["title"].GetString();
                    string date = groupObject1["publication_date"].GetString();

                    JsonArray jsonGallery = groupObject1["gallery"].GetArray();
                    foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonGallery)
                    {
                        JsonObject groupObject2 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                        string imageUrl = groupObject2.ContainsKey("image_url") && groupObject2["image_url"] != null ? groupObject2["image_url"].GetString() : string.Empty;

                        ArticleClass fileImage = new ArticleClass();
                        fileImage.ImageURL1 = imageUrl;
                        articleDatasourceDetailImage.Add(fileImage);
                    }

                    articleImageGridView.ItemsSource = articleDatasourceDetailImage;
                    articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;

                    ArticleClass file = new ArticleClass();
                    file.ID = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                    file.Title = title;
                    DateTime dateConvert = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                    file.Date = dateConvert.ToString("MMM d, yyyy");
                    articleContentDetail.NavigateToString(contentText);

                    articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;

                    articleDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    articleDetailLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException ex)
                {
                    articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
            }
        }

        private async void articleImageGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
                    articleDetailLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        articleDetailLoading.IsActive = true;
        articleDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        articleFullImageDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        var articleImageGridView = (GridView)sender;
        articleImageFullFlipview.SelectedIndex = articleImageGridView.SelectedIndex;

        articleFullImageDetailBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        articleDetailLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        articleDetailLoading.IsActive = false;
        }
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to get your data again when clicking on the item. When you load your data, set the ItemsSource of your GridView and your FlipView to be the same collection.

Second, when your item is clicked, get the SelectedIndex of the item and then set the SelectedIndex of your FlipView

```
private async Task LoadData()
{
    // get data
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    // Convert to your objects
    articleImageFullFlipview.ItemsSource = data;
    articleImageGridView.ItemsSource = data;
}

private void articleImageGridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (GridView)sender;
    articleImageFullFlipview.SelectedIndex = gridView.SelectedIndex;
    // show or hide any controls
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding the code above and deleted the code to delete the data, but on the flipview it does not display the image. Whereas if I just add the code, the image on the flipview displayed remains the first index image on the gridview (not in accordance with the user's selected image on grdiview)

Comment: Make sure that your FlipView has the same ItemsSource as the GridView and that the ItemTemplate is adjusted accordingly.

Comment: yes, i just add your code below articleImageFullFlipview.ItemsSource = imageinfos; and replace gridview with articleImageGridView and its works

Comment: After I try again and again after the image on the flipview is closed and choose another image on the gridview, the image displayed on the flipview does not match the selected image on the gridview. I have changed the code above

Comment: Is the data the same for the GridView and FlipView? Or do you **have** to get additional data when selecting an image? I thought your previous code had both was getting the data the same way. If this is the case, then do not get the data every time an item is clicked and just set the ItemsSource when  you get the data the first time. I have updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: The data on the gridview and flipview are the same data. I tried deleting the code to retrieve the data again (such as the above code that I have to change), but on flipview does not display the image (just a white box). Can you fix my code? I've changed the code above (starting from displaying images on the gridview up to displaying images on the flipview)